# Doc2Vec results not as expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, doc2vec

I'm evaluating Doc2Vec for a recommender API. I wasn't able to find a decent pre-trained model, so I trained a model on the corpus, which is about 8,000 small documents.

```
    model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=25,
                    alpha=0.025,
                    min_alpha=0.00025,
                    min_count=1,
                    dm=1)
```

I then looped through the corpus to find similar documents for each document. Results were not very good (in comparison to TF-IDF). Note this is after testing different epochs and vector sizes.

```
    inferred_vector = model.infer_vector(row['cleaned'].split())
    sims = model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=4)
```

I also tried extracting the trained vectors and using cosine_similarty, but results were oddly even worse.

```
cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(model.docvecs.vectors_docs, model.docvecs.vectors_docs)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the smallish corpus the problem?

Edit:
Prep and training code

```
def unesc(s):
    for idx, row in s.iteritems():
        s[idx] = html.unescape(row)
    return s

custom_pipeline = [
    preprocessing.lowercase,
    unesc,
    preprocessing.remove_urls,
    preprocessing.remove_html_tags,
    preprocessing.remove_diacritics,
    preprocessing.remove_digits,
    preprocessing.remove_punctuation,
    lambda s: hero.remove_stopwords(s, stopwords=custom_stopwords),
    preprocessing.remove_whitespace,
    preprocessing.tokenize
]

ds['cleaned'] = ds['body'].pipe(hero.clean, pipeline=custom_pipeline)
w2v_total_data = list(ds['cleaned'])
tag_data = [TaggedDocument(words=doc, tags=[str(i)]) for i, doc in enumerate(w2v_total_data)]

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=25,
                alpha=0.025,
                min_alpha=0.00025,
                min_count=1,
                epochs=20,
                dm=1)

model.build_vocab(tag_data)
model.train(tag_data, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)
model.save("lmdocs_d2v.model")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your training code, there could easily be errors in text prep & training. Many online code examples are bonkers wrong in their `Doc2Vec` training technique!

Note that `min_count=1` is essentially always a bad idea with this sort of algorithm: any example suggesting that was likely from a misguided author.

Is a mere `.split()` also the only tokenization applied for training? (The inference list-of-tokens should be prepped the same as the training lists-of-tokens.)

How was "not very good" and "oddly even worse" evaluated? For example, did the results seem arbitrary, or in-the-right-direction-but-just-weak?

"8,000 small documents" is a bit on the thin side for a training corpus, but it somewhat depends on "how small" – a few words, a sentence, a few sentences? Moving to smaller vectors, or more training epochs, can sometimes make the best of a smallish training set - but this sort of algorithm works best with lots of data, such that dense 100d-or-more vectors can be trained.

Comment: I just added the prep and train code. The documents are between 50 and 100 words after pre-processing. I'm gauging results by comparing against TF-IDF and they're just not as relevant. I also validated the results by checking if each document has itself as first in the list of similar docs.  About 5% don't but with TF-IDF 100% did. Also, I'm using the same pre-processing steps before using infer_vector.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details! It's still a rather small training set – around 600k words to train 8k doc-vectors plus ?-thousand unique word-vectors. `min_count=1` is almost certainly hurting, and something more like the default `min_count=5` (or higher if more data allows) likely to do better. More epochs are likely to help, given the thin data. You might be able to manage larger vectors, closer to the 100 or more most often used in this sort of algorithm, but with limited data that's uncertain. …

Comment: If there's any clumping of like examples, by topic or vocabulary, in the original ordering, breaking that (with at least one re-shuffle) may help a little. Trying the PV-DBOW mode – `dm=0` – will train *only* doc-vectors, whichoften works fast/well with short texts (& avoids diluting the training data over the full vocabulary, if you don't need per-word vectors).

Comment: Whether a document's vector left over from original bulk training is top neighbor of a re-inferred vector for the same text is often a fair test of the model's stability/generalization – whether roughly enough training, with somewhat sensible paramaers, has occurred. But given the inherent randomness/jitter from run to run, a 95% concurrence is fairly good. (If you want more consistency, more `epochs` in training and/or inference may help. You may also find the re-inferred vectors – wholly calcuated based on final model state – slightly better than the training left-overs for other purposes.)

Comment: After your comments yesterday, I tweaked the training and got much better results. 99.4% - `min_count=6, vector_size=75, epochs=125, dm=0`. Not bad!

Comment: Great to hear! But above all else, I'd try to get more training data - if not from your exact problem area, perhaps some similar domain with similar lingo/docs. With more data, you could increae the `vector_size`, do fewer `epochs` – & still likely get better results. Good luck!